# Angular.js and routeprovider tutorial stackskills

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm currently working through an angular.js tutorial on stackskills but have run into a problem.

It seems as though my use of the routeprovider isn't correct.

Each route is supposed to correlate to a link on a nav bar. However, instead of switching views it always hits the otherwise statement and displays main as opposed to any other view.

When the otherwise statement is removed, none of the views display.

```html
var app = angular.module("computer", ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/main', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    }).
    when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'about.html',
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    }).
    when('/services', {
      templateUrl: 'services.html',
      controller:'ServicesCtrl'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: 'contact.html',
      controller:'ContactCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo: "/main"})
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}])

.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  
}])

.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  
}]);
```

This is the div that houses the nav bar and links for the views

```html
<div class="container">
      <header class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Computer Solutions</h3>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light rounded mb-3">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-md-center nav-justified w-100">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/main">Home                                                       <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#/contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      </div>
       <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
         <div ng-view></div>
       </div>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried removing the /?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change much except for removing the view entirely from the page. The one it defaults to to be exact.

Comment: I see your code is correct, can you check the console?

Comment: Turns out my syntax was off


<a class="nav-link" href="#!/about">About</a> is the current method of calling a view

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my syntax was off "#!/about" is the current method of calling a view